# binding values to hiddenfield

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hidapplyuid" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" />

                        <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="UID" CssClass="" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("candUID")%>'></asp:Label>      
                                 <asp:Label ID="JobApplyUID" CssClass="" runat ="server" Text='<%#Eval("jobApplyUID")%>'></asp:Label>                         
                            </ItemTemplate>                            
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

need to bind the JobApplyUID to the hiddenfield in cs page... please help me...

Comment: The error sir, what is it?

Comment: `Value='<%#Eval("jobApplyUID")%>'`?

Comment: no error, label id get the value, hiddenfield need to get that valu sir,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `HiddenField` inside of a `TemplateField`, else it won't be databound since the `GridView`, `DetailsView`, etc cannot access it

Change from this

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidapplyuid" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" />

<asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="UID" CssClass="" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("candUID")%>'></asp:Label>      
        <asp:Label ID="JobApplyUID" CssClass="" runat ="server" Text='<%#Eval("jobApplyUID")%>'></asp:Label>                         
    </ItemTemplate>                            
</asp:TemplateField>
```

To something like this. Move it to a `TemplateField` someplace, for example

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%-- Move hidden variable inside of the template, else it cannot be databound --%>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hidapplyuid" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("jobApplyUID")%>' />
    </ItemTemplate>                            
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="UID" CssClass="" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("candUID")%>'></asp:Label>      
        <asp:Label ID="JobApplyUID" CssClass="" runat ="server" Text='<%#Eval("jobApplyUID")%>'></asp:Label>                         
    </ItemTemplate>                            
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: if i move that to grid, i cont able to access the value other than grid... i need to use that value for other purpose...

Comment: @kirk How can i get the value of hidden field through JavaScript?

Comment: You can leverage `ClientID` or use `ClientIDMode`, take a look at <https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Nov/07/ClientIDMode-in-ASPNET-40>

Answer (score 0):

Assessing controls from gridview is very easy try this demo as follows. Add new test page in your project. Lets have ASPX page as shown below...

```
<div>
    Job Apply GUID : <asp:Label runat="server" ID="uxJobApplyUID"></asp:Label>
     <asp:GridView ID="uxGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="JobApply UID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="uxHiddenJobApplyUID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("jobApplyUID") %>' />
                    <asp:Button ID="uxShowDetails" runat="server" Text="Show Data" OnClick="uxShowDetails_Click" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

And code behind will be as follows...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("jobApplyUID", typeof(string));
        dt.Rows.Add(System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        dt.Rows.Add(System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        dt.Rows.Add(System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        dt.Rows.Add(System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        dt.Rows.Add(System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        uxGrid.DataSource = dt;
        uxGrid.DataBind();
    }
}
protected void uxShowDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.uxJobApplyUID.Text = (((sender as Button).NamingContainer as GridViewRow).FindControl("uxHiddenJobApplyUID") as HiddenField).Value;
}
```

If you try this you can get value from any control present in gridview.